# Git Repository Eclipse Basics

Tags: eclipse, git

I am a student who has just started programming and have to create a project with a team of students. We are trying to find some kind of solution to code and have our work synced across everybody's workspace. Some are using linux, others windows and some mac. I have tried to understand the whole "Git" repository but am struggling to set up the basics. We are all working on eclipse and have installed the EGit but now are stuck how we set up the communal folder. I tried setting up an account on bitbucket but can't find out how we are meant to link eclipse workspace to the online folder? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to use Egit and bickbucket, consider cloning your remote repo to a local folder on your file system.

Here is a link describing the cloning procedure:https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote. You should be able to find the URI to use for the repository on bitbucket.